# Polymorphism, inheritance and generic C# : Cannot cast subclass into supertype

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, covariance

I have a problem with abstract class and generic in c# (I usually code in Java) : here is the code I would like to use :

```
public interface InterfaceResult {...}

public abstract class Result : InterfaceResult {...}   
public class ResultA : Result {...}
public class ResultB : Result {...}

public interface InterfaceKing { InterfaceResult function();}

public abstract class King : InterfaceKing {
  public abstract Result function();
}
public class KingA : King {
  public override ResultA function(){...}
}
public class KingB : King {
  public override ResultB function(){...}
}
```

but that doesn t work : Visual Studio want for KingA and KingB to return an instance of Result with function(). If i use "new" instead of override, VS say I don t implement the required method (i need to use override).

So I tried with generic and it s not better

```
public abstract class Result    {    }
public class ResultA : Result    {    }
public class ResultB : Result    {    }

public interface IKing<T>    {T function();    }

public abstract class King<Result> : IKing<Result>
{
    public abstract Result function();

    public static implicit operator King<Result>(KingB v)
    {
        return v; // generate StackOverflow Exception
    }

    public static implicit operator King<Result>(KingA v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class KingA : King<ResultA>
{
    public override ResultA Get()
    {
        return new ResultA();
    }
}

public class KingB : King<ResultB>
{
    public override ResultB Get()
    {
        return new ResultB();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    King<Result> a = new KingA(); // allowed by  public static implicit operator King<Result>(KingA v)
    King<Result> b = new KingB(); // allowed by  public static implicit operator King<Result>(KingB v)
    KingA ka = new KingA();
    List<King<Result>> lista = new List<King<Result>>();
    public void test()
    {
        lista.Add(ka);
    }        
}
```

How can i make this work ? I can t find any solution nor any good or complete example.

Comment: When you say trying with a generic is "not better", can you give a bit more detail there please?

Comment: You can't override an abstract method using a method that has a *different* signature. As for returing subclasses instead of a parent class in the definition, that's called covariance, it *is* allowed in generic interfaces but you have to specify the type as `out T` instead of just T, eg `public interface IKing<out T>    {T function();    }`

Comment: Not sure to see what good using generics here can do ? (and almost the same for the interface)

Comment: With generic, i tried to do something like inheritance/polymorphism. Like in the second code. It does not work. I dont know what to return with the public static implicit operator. I cannot cast KingA in King<ResultA>.  I also used in my real code out T. Does not work either.

Comment: inheritance/polymorphism are not related to generics

Comment: I used generic to work around my problem. Best is to use inheritance/polymorphism, I agree, but I cannot make it work. And I can t understand how to use polymorphism in C#, my first code should work.

Comment: No it shouldn't an interface/abstract contract must be fullfilled. Returning something else doesn't fullfill it even if it's a derived class. Meaning KingA and KingB override must return a `Result`

Comment: But ResultA is a Result. Result result = new ResultA(); is correct no?

Comment: In the first code, if you make your methods return `Result` but then do `return new ResultA()`, that'll work. The interface implementation must be exact.

Comment: Yes, it is in the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from "full interface" to "no interface" (for lack of better terms) all that work (this Main works fine)

```
static void Main ()
{
    King a = new KingA ();
    King b = new KingB ();
    KingA ka = new KingA ();
    List<King> list = new List<King> ();

    list.Add (a);
    list.Add (b);
    list.Add (ka);
}
```

### "full interface"

```
    public interface InterfaceResult { }

    public abstract class Result : InterfaceResult { }
    public class ResultA : Result { }
    public class ResultB : Result { }

    public interface InterfaceKing { InterfaceResult Function (); }

    public abstract class King : InterfaceKing
    {
        public abstract InterfaceResult Function ();
    }
    public class KingA : King
    {
        public override InterfaceResult Function () => new ResultA ();
    }
    public class KingB : King
    {
        public override InterfaceResult Function () => new ResultA ();
    }
```

### "mixed (less interface)"

```
    public abstract class Result { }
    public class ResultA : Result { }
    public class ResultB : Result { }

    public interface IKing { Result Function (); }

    public abstract class King : IKing
    {
        public abstract Result Function ();
    }

    public class KingA : King
    {
        public override Result Function () => new ResultA ();
    }

    public class KingB : King
    {
        public override Result Function () => new ResultB ();
        {
            return new ResultB ();
        }
    }
```

### "no interface"

```
    public abstract class Result { }
    public class ResultA : Result { }
    public class ResultB : Result { }

    public abstract class King
    {
        public abstract Result Function ();
    }

    public class KingA : King
    {
        public override Result Function () => new ResultA ();
    }

    public class KingB : King
    {
        public override Result Function () => new ResultB ();
    }
```

Comment: ok I thought i could return a subtype without problem. I ll try to cast subtype to the returned object. Thank you for your answer. I can cast the returned object to the subtype.

Comment: if you need to subtype after that it probably means you have a design problem. All kings expect a `Result` as result (pun intended). So all Result should behave the same (after all they all are Result) the concrete implementation can vary between say a `ResultA` or a `ResultB` but the behaviour of all `Result` should be consistent

Comment: I want to generalize but in some particular case, i need to be sure to have a particular subtype. That s why i cast. Am i wrong?

Comment: wrong ; not necessarily ; there are scenarios where we don't have choice ;  but most of the time it's a flawed design which is in cause. The polymorphism principle state "I want that behaviour (method) done regardless of which concrete type you really are" having to rely on which concrete type it is, it's tossing away all polymorphism benefit

Answer (score 0):

**Using covariance**

See .net fiddler [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1QdVei). Read more about [Covariance and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public abstract class Result { }

public class ResultA : Result { }

public class ResultB : Result { }

public interface IKing<out T> where T : Result {}

public abstract class King<T> : IKing<T> where T : Result
{
    public abstract T Get();
}

public class KingA : King<ResultA>
{
    public override ResultA Get()
    {
        return new ResultA();
    }
}

public class KingB : King<ResultB>
{
    public override ResultB Get()
    {
        return new ResultB();
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    King<ResultA> a = new KingA(); // allowed by  public static implicit operator King<Result>(KingA v)
    King<ResultB> b = new KingB(); // allowed by  public static implicit operator King<Result>(KingB v)
    KingA ka = new KingA();
    List<IKing<Result>> lista = new List<IKing<Result>>();

    public void Test()
    {
        lista.Add(ka);
    }        
}
```